# Generating OpenAPI C# client library in an automated fashion using msbuild instead of post build events?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi, nswag

I have a .NET 6 ASP.NET Web Api project that uses Swashbuckle. I'd like to easily generate a corresponding client library for each build/release of the API. Here is what I was thinking, from a high level:

- Make an API change to a controller, push the change up
- GitVersion calculates a semver version based on the change (fix, feat, etc)
- Pipeline builds the API project and bundles it into a docker image
- Pipeline should also generate a C# client library using the same semantic version from the API and publish that to a private Nuget feed.

The last point is the salient one as far as this question is concerned. This is the only way I know to accomplish this at the moment:

1. Create a client project in my solution along with the API project
2. Set it up to run `nswag` tool as a post-build event that spits out generated C# files
3. Compile that client project
4. Deploy the client library as a nuget package

I know that the open API spec is available at `http://localhost:5054/swagger/v1/swagger.json` while the web API is running, so in my build pipeline, I imagine I'd need to actually run a debug build of the server API in order to access it.

I don't really like this solution because it's clunky. It requires invoking a separate 3rd party command line tool and requires me to run my rest API server to access the OpenAPI spec file.

I did some googling around and I saw that there *might* be a way to greatly simplify this using [ServiceProjectReference](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/ServiceProjectReference), but I'm honestly not sure how that works. It makes it appear as if I can skip the 2 clunky parts I talked about above and drive everything from msbuild itself via XML properties.

What is the cleanest/most concise and modern way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Is there any merit to the ServiceProjectReference stuff above?

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli) ?

Comment: Yeah, and I'm actually using that right now just to get a solution. However it still requires creating custom msbuild targets and it gets quite sophisticated. Not as simple as I was hoping for in my question.